# need advice on dust temmplate

Tags: javascript, dust.js

I am completely new to dust (linkedin), just working on my first little template. After writing it the obvious (but long) way I thought of a way to optimize using an inline partial. 
The long version looks like this:

```
{#parcours}<tr class="pcsel_pc" id="{id}">
<td class="pcsel_exp_btn"><a href="#"  class="list{?exp}Hide{:else}Exp{/exp}Btn">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-{?exp}minus{:else}plus{/exp}"></span></a></td>
<td class="pcsel_col">{name}</td><td class="pcsel_col pcsel_num">{count}</td>
</tr>
{?exp}
{#variants}
<tr class="pcsel_var{?sel} pcsel_sel{/sel}" id="{id}" >
<td class="pcsel_col">&nbsp;</td><td class="pcsel_var pcsel_col">{name}</td>
<td class="pcsel_col pcsel_num">{count}</td>
</tr>
{/variants}
{:else}
{#variants}
<tr class="pcsel_var pcsel_hide" id="{id}" >
<td class="pcsel_col">&nbsp;</td><td class="pcsel_var pcsel_col">{name}</td>
<td class="pcsel_col pcsel_num">{count}</td>
</tr>
{/variants}
{/exp}
{/parcours}
```

Explanation: 
I have a context parcours that contains an inner context variants. If the variable exp does not exist in the outer context, I want to use a class pcsel_hide in the inner context. 
This solution works but the code for the inner context is contained twice which is kind of stupid. So I thought of a way to use an inline partial which is conditionally set in the outer context and used in the inner context:

```
{#parcours}<tr class="pcsel_pc" id="{id}">
<td class="pcsel_exp_btn"><a href="#"  class="list{?exp}Hide{:else}Exp{/exp}Btn">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-{?exp}minus{:else}plus{/exp}"></span></a></td>
<td class="pcsel_col">{name}</td><td class="pcsel_col pcsel_num">{count}</td>
</tr>
{?exp}{<hide/}{:else}{<hide} pcsel_hide{/hide}{/exp}
{#variants}
<tr class="pcsel_var{+hide/}{?sel} pcsel_sel{/sel}" id="{id}" >
<td class="pcsel_col">&nbsp;</td><td class="pcsel_var pcsel_col">{name}</td>
<td class="pcsel_col pcsel_num">{count}</td>
</tr>
{/variants}
{/parcours}
```

This version is nice and short, but it doesn't seem to do the job. I see the class pcsel_hide all the time even if the outer context contains exp and thus uses the correct classes. 
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because inline partials are statically evaluated before template rendering begins. The last version of an inline partial defined with the same name wins.

Inline partials cannot be conditionally evaluated like this. What you probably want instead is to use a logic helper like `{@eq}`.

Comment: Problem is that the data I am using comes from the parent context. How do I access that within {@eq}?

Comment: Dust will walk up the context if it can't find a reference to your key at the inner level. See http://www.dustjs.com/guides/contexts